# Run agt-get install imagemagick on raspberry pi using docker file

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi, docker, imagemagick, apt-get

I am new to docker in rasppberry pi. I have installed docker on my raspi, and I wanted to create a docker image. This docker image when pulled into another raspi with docker should install imagemagick using apt-get install on that raspi. I am having a difficult time in writing this simple docker file. Could anyone shed some light on this?
Thank you

Comment: This should have everything you need to know: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want the Docker container to install `imagemagick` _on its host_ (i.e. the other raspberry pi and not run the application within a container)?
If so, I'm not saying it can't be done, but I would say it's not necessarily in spirit of 'containerizing' and recommend against using Docker for this.